# Why is Esquisse greying out some plot types?

Tags: r, data-science

[image: Screenshot of my problem]
I am trying to get Esquisse to make me a normal distribution bell curve but it won't do it. Is this the limit of the add in?

I tried to look the problem up on Google but didn't find anything. Any help would be really great.